# How to use enqueu, dequeue, push, and peek in a Palindrome?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to see if a string is a palindrome. I'm having trouble with the implementing the queue.enqueue(nextCharacter), stack.push(nextCharacter), queueFront = queue.peekFront(), stackTop = stack.peek(), queue.dequeu(). I tried looking at examples online of implementations of peek(), deque, push, and enqueue. Could not find any that worked correctly. I have to follow this exact format of this program.

```
// Start of Pseudcode given: 


isPalindrome(someString: string): boolean
{


// Create an empty queue and stack

aQueue = new empty queue

aStack = new empty stack

// Add each character of string to both queue and stack

length = length of someString

for (i= 1 throught length)
{
nextChar = ith character of someString

aQueue.enqueue(nextChar)

aStack.push(nextChar)

}

charactersAreEqual=true

// Compare queue characters with stack characters

while (aQueue is not empty and charactersAreEqual)
{

queueFront = aQueue.peekFront();

stackTop = aStack.peek()

if(queueFront equals stackTop)
{

aQueue.dequeue();

aStack.pop()
}
else {

charactersAreEqual = false

}







#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>


bool isPalindrome(std::string str) {
    // Declare variables
    int length;
    char nextCharacter;
    bool charactersEqual;
    char queueFront;
    char stackTop;
    

    // Create an empty queue and stack
    std::queue<char> queue;
    std::stack<char> stack;

    // Set lenth to length of string 
    length = str.length();

    // Add each character of string to both queue and stack
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        nextCharacter = str.at(i);
        queue.enqueue(nextCharacter); // ??????
        stack.push(nextCharacter); // ?????

    }
    // Set characters to true
    charactersEqual = true;
    
    // Compare queue characters with stack characters
    while (!queue.empty() && charactersEqual) {
        queueFront = queue.peekFront(); // ?????
        stackTop = stack.peek(); // ?????

        if (queueFront == stackTop) {
            queue.dequeu(); // ?????
            stack.pop();
        }
        else {
            charactersEqual = false;
        }
    }
    return charactersEqual;  // return characters that are equal

}
```

Comment: also use the interface for the class you are using. There's no "enqueue" function or "peekFront" see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

Comment: I'm suppose to follow a specific pseudocode version that involves enqueue and peekFront. I have changed the stack and queue to use char.

Comment: Why not simply create a class that has a `std::queue<char>` as a member?

Comment: I verified that your code works on at least two test cases if you make the minor changes suggested by Sergey and myself. (I didn't fully test it or anything, or even read the code really. I just fixed where the IDE gave error messages.)

Comment: Okay, I'm suppose to follow a certain pseudocode given. I will post the pseudocode that was given for this assignment.

Comment: I have posted the pseudocode that I must follow for this code.

Answer (score 0):

For an ASCII string, you can:

```
bool result = std::equal(str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin(), str.rend());
```

If you are using Unicode then you should probably reverse the whole string then use the equality operator:

```
bool isPalindrome(std::u8string str)
{
    // Less efficient
    std::u8string rstr{str};

    std::reverse(rstr.begin(), rstr.end());

    return (str == str2);
}
```

For instance, is 'é' and 'e' the same letter? In Dutch, "één hond" and "een hond" are the same because the first means "one dog" and the second can mean either "one dog" or "a dog" depending on the context. Therefore, you need to be careful if you need internationalization.

Comment: In UTF-8, some characters are represented by multiple bytes and some are represented as a single byte. Also, multiple different characters can be considered equivalent to one another which may vary by locale. Now you point out the `std::reverse` operation and I read back my own description, I doubt my answer is correct for for UTF-8 strings because the order of the bytes in multibyte characters will also be reversed.

Comment: It seems I was correct about a potential problem in UTF-8 strings. When I posted my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973548/properly-checking-for-palindromes-using-utf-8-strings-in-c), it seems any UTF encoding will cause problems because there are equivalent sequences for some strings. For searches and comparisons, you must [normalize](http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) the strings first. Also, I found the [Unicode Study Group (SG16)](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) for more information about text processing in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from a program I wrote a while ago that checks if a word is a palindrome. I know it's not what you're asking for, but I figured I'd put it out there.

```
bool isPalindrome(const string word)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = word.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        if (word[i] != word[j])   //If any comparison fails, return false
            return false;
    }

    //If all the checks passed, return true
    return true
}
```