# Properly checking for palindromes using UTF-8 strings in C++

Tags: c++, c++20

When trying to answer a question, [How to use enqueu, dequeue, push, and peek in a Palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972457/how-to-use-enqueu-dequeue-push-and-peek-in-a-palindrome/67972736#67972736), I suggested a palindrome can be found using `std::string` by:

```
bool isPalindrome(const std::string str)
{
    return std::equal(str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin(), str.rend());
}
```

For a Unicode string, I suggested:

```
bool isPalindrome(const std::u8string str)
{
    std::u8string rstr{str};

    std::reverse(rstr.begin(), rstr.end());

    return str == rstr;
}
```

I now think this will create problems when you have multibyte characters in the string because the byte-order of the multibyte character is also reversed. Also, some characters will be equivalent to each other in different locales. Therefore, in C++20:

1. how do you make the comparison robust to multibyte characters?
2. how do you make the comparison robust to different locales when there can be equivalency between multiple characters?

Comment: You need to convert to `UTF-32` or it gets somewhat complicated.

Comment: Aswell as utf32, you'll probably want to convert it to a normalised (canonical) form aswell. http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html. Text is hard.

Comment: There are problems not only with multibyte characters but with also with combining characters and complex scripts like Devanagari and who knows what else. UTF-32 won't help here.

Answer (score 6):

Reversing a Unicode string becomes non-trivial. Converting from UTF-8 to UTF-32/UCS-4 is a good start, but not sufficient by itself--Unicode also has combining code points, so two (or more) consecutive code points form a single resulting grapheme (the added code point(s) add(s) diacritic marking to the base character), and for things to work correctly, you need to keep these in the correct order.

So, basically instead of code points, you need to divide the input up into a series of graphemes, and reverse the order of the graphemes, not just the code points.

To deal with multiple different sequences of code points that represent the same sequence of characters, you normally want to do normalization. There are four different normalization forms. In this case, you'd *probably* want to use NFC or NFD (should be equivalent for this purpose). The NFKC/NFKD forms are primarily for compatibility with other character sets, which it sounds like you *probably* don't care about.

This can also be non-trivial though. Just for one well known example, consider the German character "ß". This is sort of equivalent to "ss", but only exists in lower-case, since it never occurs at the beginning of a word. So, there's probably room for argument about whether something like `Ssaß` is a palindrome or not (for the moment ignoring the minor detail that it's not actually a word). For palindromes, most people ignore letter case, so it would be--but your code in the question seems to treat case as significant, in which case it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: For more thorough confusion, the uppercase ß is now officially added to Unicode.

Comment: So the palindrome check logic needs to normalize the string, lowercase the string (since foldcase will probably have other issues), break up the string into a vector of single grapheme strings, ignore uninteresting characters (like spaces and punctuation), and then it can `std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), v.rbegin(), v.rend())`.  Simple as pie!

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this is a non-trivial problem. I know a similar problem in Dutch: "There is one dog. There is a dog" is ["Er is één hond. Er is een hond."](https://translate.google.com/?sl=nl&tl=en&text=Er%20is%20%C3%A9%C3%A9n%20hond.%20Er%20is%20een%20hond.&op=translate). Now I investigate further, there is currently a proposal for UTF encodings in the [standard library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1629r1.html). The Unicode Study Group (SG16) have more papers [here](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16).